# Problems composing php sql query for postgresql table using LIKE

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am trying to retrieve data from a postgresql table therefore I have written a code. Now I am trying to compose the sql query but it isn't working. With my query I am trying to search in the table genes_searchterms and find all geneID matching where in the column types the value is equal to Pathway and where in the column searchterm the word aging is present.
Bellow the code to compose my query:

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT DISTINCT \"gene_id\" FROM \"" . \"genes_searchterms\" .
 "\" WHERE ". "(\"types\" LIKE  '". \"Pathway\" . "' 
AND  \"searchterm\" LIKE '" . \"%aging%\" ."') ";
```

Is there something wrong in the composition of my query? I use drupal and I don't get any errors when executing the code. I can't figure out where I got it wrong. 
I use PostgreSQL 9.2.23. 
In the fiddle is a part displayed of my table
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t7ThJ7Aen9XYzv2EtepinP/0

Comment: "but it isn't working" is not a helpful description of what's going wrong. "I don't get any useful error" is better, but still not enough. Start with your version of Postgres ... And don't make it harder for us by displaying two *different* queries.

Comment: The query you show and the query the script can produce are never the same. For instance one uses `"` around the identifiers, the other doesn't, one has `DISTINCT "gene_id"` as column list, the other has `searchterm`, one has `"searchterm" ~* ` in the `WHERE` clause, the other `searchterm LIKE`...

Comment: please try to simplify your example to one condition and show the code without variables. Please add a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pzi4KX49Rfhrt9YP7RAthW/0) to you Example

Comment: I added a fiddle and remove my variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to get your Query up and running in [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pzi4KX49Rfhrt9YP7RAthW/0). I also got no result, so I rechecked your condition and tried them separately. The error was in the "searchterm" condition.

You're using the ~* operator wich matches, according to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-matching.html), a Regex case insensitive. Since % isn't a pattern in Regex it matches "%aging%" literally. Only if you use LIKE in the query. % will be used as a wild card.

You could ether use a correct Regex or switch to LIKE.